# Formatting time in php like mysql's date_format

Tags: php

How can we format time in php like we do using mysql's date_format?

In mySql we do  `date_format(now(),'%M %e, %Y') as time`. Can php's current time be formatted to make it look like January 3, 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Check out [PHP date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
echo date('F j, Y', time());
```

Comment: I don't understand why people down vote an answer that provides an answer to the question being asked.

Comment: I wonder why the d part never works for me. Because i'm on windows 7?

Comment: What "d part" are you talking about?

Comment: d Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros or even j Day of the month without leading zeros

Comment: The code above works just fine. It should work for you too. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

The code is:

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime(date()))
```

More information [on the date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [some information on the strtotime() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Why only 3 function calls? Can't you use some more?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ok, then please use the date function and set the second argument to be a date instead of unix timestamp. Seems your common sense can't think if this as an example on how to use all these functions. Have you even considered the option that the author gets the date from a MySQL date field ?